Battery thermal loss
A copper bus bar is subject to a short circuit current of 500 A for 10 s. The section of the bus bar, through which the current flows, has a length L = 50 mm and a cross section of A = 20 mm^2. Approximate the thermal energy released in the bus bar due to the current, assuming a resistivity for copper of 1.7 x 10^-8 Ohm*m. Give your answer in Joules. Assume the same copper bus bar as in the previous question, which now has a total mass of m = 150 g. During the short circuit 405 J of energy are released. Approximate the average temperature increase of the bus bar in degrees Celsius [°C] using appropriate assumptions. Please state the assumptions you made. 

We might look at homework IF you have made a valid attempt, otherwise VTC.

I assume you haven't tried anything yet.  This is simple i-squared-r stuff plus heat capacity.  Also I've never had a homework problem where the text didn't explain the concepts already.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
